# Can i deserialize object back to original interface even if all the concrete types now reference new version of interface

Tags: c#, serialization, remoting

I am running into this massive problem, I have to for various reasons change the Interface defintion to something different. This interface was serialised as a blob into the database. Now i am trying to do the migration of old blob into new blob . But i have managed to maintain the original contract defintion side by side to my modified interface definition. But all the concrete types which were to reference the old interface now reference the new modified version of the interface.

Only old interface defintion exists in my code base. So when i am trying to load this blob back from database to old contract defintion i get

"Object cannot be stored in an array of this type" error while deserializing.  Can someone please help.?...

Also do i still need old version of concrete types while trying to de-serialize the blob back into old interface defintion?.

any help would be appreciated. As i am really stuck.

Thanks,
AG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the SurrogateSelector class ? It can help in taking control of deserialization when such a change of class is needed.